# ResKit Core Data saving cache

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using RestKit 0.22 and I need to use multiple sqlite databases in my project. Create and using multiple databases is not a problem itself. My problem is that ResKit uses cache before saving data. It's happening with one database and works perfectly but with multiple databases, my datas are often saved in a wrong database. If I connect one database and I call a web service the datas are kept in cache. If i connect an other database and I call the same web service the datas of both calls are saved in the second database.

I tried to use `RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache` instead of `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache` for managedObjectCache in `RKManagedObjectStore` but that doesn't work.

I also tried to save the datas manually with `[[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] persistentStoreManagedObjectContext] save:nil]` in the success bloc and I got the same result.

I also used RestKit's example RKTwitterCoreData to validate that other parts of my code weren't causing my problem. I was able to reproduce easily by simply removing de seeding part of RKTwitterCoreData and run it. I used iExplorer to get sqlite file from my app. When I opened it, it was empty. The second time I ran the app, the database was feeded.

Is it possible to force RestKit to save datas at the moment it receives it or before I connect an other database?

Thanks

Comment: How are you switching databases (and why)? RestKit does save immediately, but if you switch the backing you should tear down and recreate the entire Core Data stack...

Comment: The problem happens even if I doesn't change database when app is running. If I run the app the first time and connect the first database. When I close the app this database is empty. If I run the app a second time and connect the second database. The datas from my first and second launch will be in my second database.

Comment: You'll need to show all your code

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/j3ieckgd5syfcnr/RKTwitterCoreData_Demo.zip

(- Based on the Restkit demo, just a small modification)